# Did William Shakespeare say "I always feel happy..."?

Tags: history, quotes, literature, william-shakespeare

Is the attribution of this quote to William Shakespeare correct?

> I always feel happy. You know why? Because I don’t expect anything from anyone. Expectations always hurt… Life is short… So love your life… Be happy… And keep smiling… Just live for yourself and…
>   Before you speak? Listen..
>   Before you write? Think..
>   Before you spend? Earn..

This quote is widely used as a status line in social networks. 
Examples: [top quotes collection](http://topquotescollection.com/authors/william-shakespeare/), [tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/william-shakespeare?before=1316520767), [blog entry](http://www.ultimatepotentialblog.com/2010/10/shakespeare-said.html).
I failed to find the source of this quote in the works of Shakespeare. Can someone prove or disprove this attribution?

Comment: Doesn't sound like The Bard. But who knows, it could be a reworded sonnet.

Comment: my brain is playing tricks to me, for a moment I read william shatner instead of william shakespeare

Comment: This sounds like one of those chain emails. You know the ones made of a mishmash of unattributed cut and pasted quotes written in a really big pink and red fonts with a couple of silly pictures of dogs.

Comment: @jwenting, agree. It really doesn't sound like Shakespeare.

Comment: Perhaps this comes from someone making more of what Shakespeare did say and then people attributing it directly to Shakespeare over time.
Here is what Shakespeare did say about expectations:
“Expectation is the root of all heartache.”

Comment: @KevinFitzMaurice Thanks for another example of a quote incorrectly attributed to Shakespeare! :)

Comment: Sounds like Buddha

Comment: "No, that was Einstein." — Shakespeare

Comment: @santiagozky William Shatner would be a much more believable source for these quotes.

Comment: This sounds about as unlike Shakespeare as possible.

Comment: @user25152 Wrong ... Shakespeare didn't say that, either.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I can see that part of the text in the post is taken from another set of quotes by [William Arthur Ward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Arthur_Ward)

> **Before You By William Arthur Ward**
>
> Before you speak, listen.
>
> Before you write, think.
>
> Before you spend, earn.
>
> Before you invest, investigate.
>
> Before you criticize, wait.
>
> Before you pray, forgive.
>
> Before you quit, try.
>
> Before you retire, save.
>
> Before you die, give.

I've also run keyword searches on two Shakespeare search engines [1](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~matty/Shakespeare/nsearch.cgi) [1](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-advanced.php) and cannot find phrases such as "Expectations always hurt" and "Keep smiling" at all.

So I'm going to say the passage you've posted is NOT by Shakespeare - at least, not all of it.

On a sidenote - one phrase which did exist is "Life is short"

> Henry IV, Part I [V, 2]
>
> I cannot read them now.  O gentlemen, the time of life is short!

Shakespeare, however, did say something similar to "Expectations always hurt" in [All's Well That Ends Well](http://www2.hn.psu.edu/faculty/jmanis/shakesp/allswell.pdf).

> Oft expectation fails and most oft there

Comment: brilliant work deciphering its authenticity and origin :)

Comment: "Oft expectation fails, and most oft there /
Where most it promises; and oft it hits /
Where hope is coldest, and despair most fits."